# Breadcrumb in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

How to display Breadcrumb feature in ExtJS designs.

Iam using Panel with borderlayout, i want to design crumb feature on top of panel
please send me some samples.....

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two solutions come to my mind.

1. **Use the panel title**. You will have to manipulate the title of your panel and create the breadcrumb on it. You will have to create the breadcrumb text, set it to the panel's title. Here is what you might do:

Initially, you may set it to have just the text home `title: 'Home'`. At some point of time you update it using `setTitle()` method. Here is an example:

```
panel.setTitle('Home >> ' + '<a id="levelone" href="#">Level 1</a>');
```

You need to have a logic to you create the anchor tag and its id. The id is important because, we will use it to associate the action. Lets say I have a function sayHello and I call it when "Level 1" is clicked:

```
var sayHello = function(){
    alert('Hello Text');
}
```

Associating this function to the user click of the Level 1 is done using events:

```
var level1 = Ext.get('levelone');
level1.on('click', sayHi);
```

2.**Use the tbar**. If you don't plan to make use of the tbar for the said panel, you can make use of it as your breadcrumb holder. In this method, you can add actions, or toolbar items to the toolbar. Here is an example:

```
var action = new Ext.Action({
    text: 'Level 1',
    handler: function(){
        Ext.Msg.alert('Action', 'Level 1...');
    }               
});

var action1 = new Ext.Action({
    xtype: 'tbtext',
    text: 'Level 2',
    handler: function(){
        Ext.Msg.alert('Action', 'Level 2...');
    }               
});
```

And in your panel you can have:

```
tbar: [
 action,'-',action1,'-',action2
]
```

You will have to change the CSS for the separator to show ">>" or other symbols you plan to use. In this case, you will have to use the Toolbar's `add` & `remove` methods to manipulate the breadcrumb.

Comment: ThanQ very much for your replay,In my scenario setTitle is most suitable....thanq

Answer (score 1):

EXT 6 has breadcrumb Ext.toolbar.Breadcrumb xtype:breadcrumb as native component. It accepts tree store and has some problem such as updating the root node. Also after updating store you need to call set selection explicitly on the newly added record.

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Breadcrumb', {
            store: "[any tree.store]",
            useSplitButtons: false,
            enableFocusableContainer: false,
            rootVisible: true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. It's a plugin...extension for the ext toolbar to make breadcrumbs. It has an example how to use it.
https://github.com/scirelli/ExtjsBreadCrumbs