# ExtJS4: this.ownerCt in initComponent function

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there any way to access the parent component (via this.ownerCt) in the initComponent function?

While trying to access it via this.ownerCt, i found out that the ownerCt attribute is set *after* initComponent. So I do not know how i can hook in the initialization process of my component where i can change some parent's attributes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to build a breadcrumb navigation, therefore i want to add my current "path" to the parent's tbar.

Comment: ownerCt is container which contain current component. Can you explain in more details how exactly it's gonna work? What kind of components are you trying to create and how you will build breadcrumbs...

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645609/breadcrumb-in-extjs) I want to use the second approach in the answer. So I want to change the tbar of the parent TabPanel from the initComponent function of my tabView. @sha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer the question directly. I would have placed this in the comments to your question but I'm not allowed yet it would appear. If you are building breadcrumbs. I would look at extending the tab panel and creating a plugin for the Tab Bar that creates the kinda of navigation you want.

```
Ext.define('HOD.plugins.Breadcrumbs', {

    // private
    init : function(tabBar) {
        tabBar.on('beforeadd', this.addIcons, this);
        tabBar.on('beforeremove', this.handleTabRemove, this);
    },

    addIcons: function(tabBar, newTab, index, options) {
        if (index > 0) {
            newTab.iconCls = 'icon-arrow';
            tabBar.items.each(function(tab) {
                if (tab != newTab) {
                    tab.overCls = 'breadcrumbs-over'
                }
            });
        }
    },

    handleTabRemove: function(tabBar, oldTab, options) {
        var count = tabBar.items.getCount();
        if (count > 1) {
            var newTab = tabBar.items.getAt(count-2);
            newTab.overCls = '';
            newTab.removeCls('x-tab-breadcrumbs-over');
        }
    }
});
```

Then extend the tab panel so it uses the above plugin to style the tabs correctly.

```
Ext.define('HOD.view.GlobalNavigation', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    border: false,
    alias: 'widget.content',
    requires: ['HOD.plugins.Breadcrumbs'],
    tabBar: {
        cls: 'breadcrumbs',
        plugins: ['tabbarbreadcrumbs']
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        this.on('tabchange', this.handleTabChange, this);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    push: function(tab) {
        this.add(tab);
        this.setActiveTab(tab);
    },

    pop: function() {
        // Get the current cards;
        var cards = this.getLayout().getLayoutItems();
        if (cards.length > 1) {
            this.setActiveTab(cards[cards.length-2]);
        }
    },

    handleTabChange: function (tabPanel, newCard, oldCard, options) {
        var cards = tabPanel.getLayout().getLayoutItems();

        for (var i = (cards.length - 1); i > 0; i--) {
            if (cards[i] !== newCard) {
                this.remove(cards[i]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I've written up post about it [here if you need more detail](http://www.jamiesutherland.com/2012/03/13/extjs-4-breadcrumbs-plugin-for-tab-panel/).

Comment: Great work Jamie - you should post your plugin on Sencha forums.

Comment: I will do. I've got a few UI parts I want to put up on github in the near future once I've cleaned them up a little for public consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend changing anything in the container from the inside element functions. Instead I would create an event in the element, fire that event and listen for it in the container.

This way your component will notify the container to do something, and container will do it itself.